# Voting on closed questions

Tags: discussion

Why is it that i have a question that was closed but users can continue to downvote it?

1. Am i misunderstanding what a closed question is?

   I thought a closed question was such that it is locked from either being seen, answered, or commented on
2. Does a closed question imply that users are not allowed to ask that particular question which was closed (since questions cannot be asked twice)?
3. Is it okay to ask a different user to post a question that i had previously asked which was closed?

Apologies, im still learning and i dont quite understand this whole "closed question" stuff

For reference purposes the question was: Why exactly do we use regulators for infinite sums? and was closed due to being "unclear" (still seems like a really clearly worded question to me /shrug).

Answer (score 3):

1. A closed question can no longer have answers added to it (well, there is a grace period for answers started before the close took effect, but it is limited and post-close answers are rare). Closing a question means that the users voting for that state believe that it is not *currently* suitable for the site (and indeed the phrase "on hold" is used for the first few days to emphasize the potential for reversing the state). A subsequent set of users can reverse a closure under the same sort of rules that we used to close it in the first place. This is all part of the normal workflow for rating and moderating questions.

   Closed question should either be edited to make them suitable or they can be expected to remain closed indefinitely.

   Closed questions can still be voted on and edited. Comments can be made to the question and all un-deleted answers.

   If it is your question *and* it does not have an up-voted or accepted answer you can delete it.

   Locking a question is different from closing it. It signifies that the question is in someway unusual and needs to be handled outside the usual workflow. Locked question can neither be edited, voted on, nor commented on.
2. If a question remains closed it means a quorum of high-rep users believe it is not suitable for the site. Re-posting an identical question is clearly inappropriate, as it offering only a slight variation that does not address the reason for the closure. **Edit the original instead.**

   You may ask a substantially different question on the same topic, but if you post it shortly after the closure of the original it will be subject to considerable scrutiny. Seriously, edit the original.

   The first edit to a closed question posts it to the review queue for re-consideration. High-rep users will see it there and act (or not) as they judge best. So, make that edit count. Find out what was wrong with the original, understand the policy under which it was closed and *craft* the edit to make it clear that your question is now in a form suitable for the site.
3. Working around the rule in part 2 is just as bad as re-posting it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. I did edit the question and that is why it was closed. Are questions regarding regularization simply frowned upon by physics SE? Is it considered a mathematics topic or something?

Comment: I took no part in the closure of the original question. It's not a subject I have more than passing knowledge about. You *have* to find out why the used who voted to close it didn't like and address their concerns.

Comment: In addition: you edit the original. The first one. I locked the second one because you kept trying to make an end-run around that basic rule. I'm not going to un-lock the second one just because you made an entirely inappropriate edit to the first one. Fix the ***first*** one.

Comment: Sorry...i wasnt thinking or saying youre the one that closed it.  Im just asking in general is questions about regularization are not allowed.  The reason says the question was unclear but im guessing this was just a place holder for the more specific reason.  E.g. the question was "why exactly do we use regulators for infinite sums?" So i dont think it was closed due to being unclear

Comment: wait, what!?!?!  What's an "end-run"?

Comment: Find out from the people who closed your question—if they will still respond to your comments—why they closed it. I'm not an expert in that area, I'm a greasy handed wrench and soldering iron physicsist, and I *will not* give you an answer or even an opinion on the place your question might have on [physics.se].

Comment: sorry....i saw you had 50,000 points and figured you might know

Comment: This is all so confusing to me :/  anyways, i labeled the question as deleted.  Im just considering regularization as offtopic on physics SE

Comment: at any rate thanks again for kindly answering my question in the OP